# Flask hidden input doesn't get set in template

Tags: python, html, flask

So I'm trying to pass a value from a Jinja2 template back to my Python code. I'm trying to do this with a hidden input. My form class is this:

```
class TrueOrFalseForm(flask_wtf.FlaskForm):
    choice = RadioField(choices=[('True', 'TRUE'), ('False', 'FALSE')], validators=[validators.InputRequired()])
    hidden = HiddenField()
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

And my form is this:

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="" method="post">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <div style="display: inline-block">
            {{ form.choice }}
            {{ form.hidden(value="{{ result }}") }}
            {{ form.submit(class_="btn btn-primary btn-lg") }}
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

`result` is a string that I'm passing when rendering the template.

When checking the value of `form.hidden.data`, though, it comes back as `''`. The tag also renders as `<input id="hidden" name="hidden" type="hidden" value="">`.

I've also tried doing `value={{ result }}` instead of `value="{{result}}"` but that makes Jinja throw a TemplateSyntaxError.

Any idea on how to do this?

**EDIT:**
I'm overwriting `result` every time I call the function.
This is my route function:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    form = forms.TrueOrFalseForm()
    x = random.randint(-100, 100)
    y = random.randint(-100, 100)
    statement_str = generate_statement_string(2)
    tree = BinTree.build_tree(statement_str)
    statement_result = BinTree.solve_tree(tree, x, y) # result gets overwritten here
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if not flask_login.current_user.is_anonymous:
            # same as the else, except with some sql, not relevant
        else:
            if form.choice.data == form.hidden.data:
                flask.flash('Correct!')
            else:
                flask.flash('Incorrect!')
    return flask.render_template('home.html', x_value=str(x), y_value=str(y), statement=statement_str,
                             result=str(statement_result), form=form)
```

Comment: what about?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619558/wtforms-hidden-field-value

Comment: @jmunsch Didn't work for me as I change the value between renders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{{ form.hidden(value="{{ result }}") }}` is already in templating syntax with the outer double curly brackets. Therefore, you should just be able to plainly write the result variable, like this: `{{ form.hidden(value=result) }}`

**EDIT**

Replace `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}` with `{{ form.csrf_token() }}` as well as doing what is in my original answer.
You may also have to instantiate the form with `form = forms.TrueOrFalseForm(request.form)`. Some forms behave weirdly if you don't do that.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I'm just getting an empty string.

Comment: @BarakNehmad I edited my answer. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}` in your template, you do not need to explicitly render the `hidden` form field. It will be included in the `hidden_tag()` call.

You can set the value of the hidden field in your views before rendering the template.

**views.py**

```
form.hidden.data = result

return render_template("index.html",form=form)
```

**index.html**

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="" method="post">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <div style="display: inline-block">
            {{ form.choice }}
            {{ form.submit(class_="btn btn-primary btn-lg") }}
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Problem is, `result` gets overwritten every time I call the function. I've added my `def home()` to the original question to reflect this.

Comment: I'm not sure why that's a problem - when you call `home` you calculate `result` and assign it to `form.hidden.data` so it can get rendered in the template. Then when you submit the form you aren't concerned with the newly generated `result`, only with the submitted `choice` and `hidden` input fields.

Comment: But for some reason it doesn't: when assigning `result` to `form.hidden.data`, the `form.data` dict gets updated with the new data, therefore working with not the submitted `hidden`, but with the new `hidden`. I'm still getting `Incorrect` when submitting the correct choice.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is:

```
<input type="hidden" id="locphoto" value="{{ mbrs.photoName|safe }}" />
```

Previous answer are correct but I think they need some correction putting ***safe*** in variable jinja:

[image: hidden field set values]