# Flask-Admin: How to get the object being edited in validate_form

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I am trying to implement custom validation in the edit form. However, I don't know how to obtain the object that is being edited in the method `validate_form`.

```py
class ShiftModelView(ModelView):
    """ModelView to manage Shift model."""

    def validate_form(self, form) -> bool:
        """Validate form."""
        if not super().validate_form(form):
            return False

        if form.scheduled_from.data >= form.scheduled_to.data:
            message = (
                "'Scheduled From' cannot be greater than or equal to 'Scheduled To'"
            )
            flash(message, "error")
            return False
        # HERE I NEED THE OBJECT THAT IS BEING EDITED
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I assume you're using WTForms from the syntax? When you say I need the object that is being edited, are you talking about a row in your database that's accessed through sqlalchemy and this form's purpose is to edit it's fields?

Comment: @barryodev, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `form` has a protected member `_obj` that is the current object being edited.

```
def validate_form(self, form) -> bool:
    """Validate form."""
    if not super().validate_form(form):
        return False

    if form.scheduled_from.data >= form.scheduled_to.data:
        message = (
            "'Scheduled From' cannot be greater than or equal to 'Scheduled To'"
        )
        flash(message, "error")
        return False

    # HERE I NEED THE OBJECT THAT IS BEING EDITED
    
    print(form._obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a [hidden field](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#convenience-fields) to your wtform class to hold the object id, you can use this to load the object from your validate_form method. Add this field to your wtform class:

```
object_id = HiddenField("Object ID")
```

In your route where you populate your form, set the object_id:

```
ShiftForm.object_id = id
```

Add it to your jinja template:

```
{{ form.object_id }}
```

Then in the validate_form you should be able to access it with `form.object_id.data` and use the ID to pull the rest of the object out of the database.

The wiring might be slightly off due to different variable names but the first answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619558/wtforms-hidden-field-value) has a working minimal example of using a wtform's hidden field, follow that and you should be good.

Comment: I meant that I need the object in `validate_form()` method not in the template.

Comment: As I said in my answer if the ID is stored on the form as a hidden field, you'll be able to get the object from the database using that id in validate_form()